# Force input to harmonic oscillator force as function of time or displacement as function of time?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy

Question title basically says it. If the governing equations are like:

$$x''m_1 = c({x_1}'-{x_2}') + k_1({x_1}'-{x_2}') = f(t)$$
etc...

Since all the terms are force terms, shouldn't the input match the units and be a function of force with respect to time? This is very confusing. The equation is expecting a force but getting a displacement.

So for instance, in this matlab tutorial of the quarter car model, the height of the bump in the road is the same as the height of the input step function. 1 cm height bump is modeled as 1 cm height step function. The following images are just snippets to show what I am referring to:

http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Suspension&section=ControlStateSpace

[image]
[image]

Again, This paper uses a sin function to model speed hump with the amplitude of the sin function = the height of the bump.

https://peer.asee.org/on-the-analysis-and-design-of-vehicle-suspension-systems-going-over-speed-bumps.pdf

[image]

So my question is, if you make the step input a height of 1 cm, that doesn't seem to take into account the velocity of the vehicle. The suspension will respond differently to the same physical height at different speeds. Therefore, it seems to make more sense to to calculate the impulse experienced by the wheel using:

$$Ft = mv$$

and with an estimated change in time and change in velocity and get the average force on the wheel. Then use *that* force as the height of the step input. So let's say you get F= 50 kN then the step height would *not* be 1 cm but 50 kN. The only thing I could think is that you would set the velocity initial conditions of the masses to the desired velocity at which you want to analyze.

In other words, why this?

$$Diff. equation = displacement(t)$$

and not this?

$$Diff. equation = force(t)$$

Comment: *"The equation is expecting a force but getting a displacement."* - I'm not sure what you mean by this.  The differential equation involves the displacement and time derivatives of the displacement.  But, as you point out, each term has dimensions of force and so the inhomogeneous 'forcing' term must also have units of force.  Note that you can divide the differential equation through by the mass $m$ and then each term has dimensions of acceleration.

Comment: Can you please explain your equation? Where are you "getting a displacement"? Of course the units in either side of an equation must be the same. Also your final paragraph confuses me even more.

Comment: Ok I updated to attempt a clarification

Comment: @AaronStevens, I am getting a "displacement" because as the wheel rolls over a step-up bump of a given height, the wheel will be displaced. So my question is why would this value be the input to the diff. EQs, rather than the magnitude of the force delivered by the bump of the given height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting a "displacement" because as the wheel rolls over a
>   step-up bump of a given height, the wheel will be displaced. So my
>   question is why would this value be the input to the diff. EQs, rather
>   than the magnitude of the force delivered by the bump of the given
>   height?

It's true that the the input stimulus to this system is the displacement $W$ but it's not true that the forcing functions for the associated differential equations are a displacement.

Look at the matrix equations (1) - (3) at the link and see that one of the scalar equations is

$$\ddot{Y}_1 = \frac{K_2}{M_2}X_1 - \left(\frac{K_1}{M_1} + \frac{K_1}{M_2} + \frac{K_2}{M_2}\right)Y_1 + U\left(\frac{1}{M_1} + \frac{1}{M_2}\right) - \frac{K_2}{M_2}W$$

which can be rearranged as so

$$\ddot{Y}_1 + \left(\frac{K_1}{\mu}+\frac{K_2}{M_2}\right)Y_1 - \frac{K_2}{M_2}X_1 - \frac{U}{\mu} = -\frac{K_2}{M_2}W$$

where

$$\frac{1}{\mu} \equiv \frac{1}{M_1} + \frac{1}{M_2}$$
and so the forcing function to this differential equation *is a function of $W$* (with dimensions of acceleration) but isn't identical to $W$.